# Special characters in document.location.href

Tags: apache, seo, href, location-href

Is it bad practice to make a page that has a web address like these:

```
http://example.com/-products-and-services.php
http://example.com/-contact-us.php
http://example.com/--books.php
http://example.com/--translation.php
http://example.com/--illustration.php
http://example.com/-$-special-feature.php
http://example.com/-$-vip-area.php
```

Will google or apache have problems with these (- $) characters?

I am doing this because I makes it easier for me to view and categorise pages while still letting me add keywords to the file names.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

You can use alphanumerics, and the special characters "$-_.+!*'()," in url.
But it may not be very helpful with seo, search engine indexing etc.
You can read what google says here,
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329?hl=en